# Parquet / pyarrow: Malformed levels

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I use Azure Stream Analytics which converts some json documents in parquet files.

For most of them, I can read them after but for some of them I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py", line 677, in scan_contents
    return self.reader.scan_contents(column_indices,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pyarrow/_parquet.pyx", line 1389, in pyarrow._parquet.ParquetReader.scan_contents
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 115, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: Malformed levels. min: 0 max: 4 out of range.  Max Level: 3
```

The parquet file schema is generated by pyarrow itself. When I print it, I get this:

```
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x12cc86d00>
required group field_id=-1 root {
  optional group field_id=-1 hierarchy {
    optional binary field_id=-1 content (String);
    optional group field_id=-1 reference {
      optional binary field_id=-1 type (String);
      optional binary field_id=-1 value (String);
    }
    optional int64 field_id=-1 quantity;
    optional group field_id=-1 children (List) {
      repeated group field_id=-1 list {
        optional group field_id=-1  {
          optional binary field_id=-1 content (String);
          optional group field_id=-1 reference {
            optional binary field_id=-1 type (String);
            optional binary field_id=-1 value (String);
          }
          optional int64 field_id=-1 quantity;
          optional group field_id=-1 children (List) {
            repeated group field_id=-1 list {
              optional group field_id=-1  {
                optional binary field_id=-1 content (String);
                optional group field_id=-1 reference {
                  optional binary field_id=-1 type (String);
                  optional binary field_id=-1 value (String);
                }
                optional int64 field_id=-1 quantity;
                repeated binary field_id=-1 children (String);
                optional group field_id=-1 assets (List) {
                  repeated group field_id=-1 list {
                    optional group field_id=-1  {
                      optional binary field_id=-1 content (String);
                      optional binary field_id=-1 type (String);
                    }
                  }
                }
                repeated binary field_id=-1 sharing_units (String);
                optional group field_id=-1 specific_data (List) {
                  repeated group field_id=-1 list {
                    optional group field_id=-1  {
                      optional group field_id=-1 target_organization {
                        optional binary field_id=-1 id (String);
                      }
                      optional binary field_id=-1 content (String);
                    }
                  }
                }
                repeated binary field_id=-1 validation_rules (String);
                repeated binary field_id=-1 metadata (String);
              }
            }
          }
          repeated binary field_id=-1 assets (String);
          repeated binary field_id=-1 sharing_units (String);
          repeated binary field_id=-1 specific_data (String);
          repeated binary field_id=-1 validation_rules (String);
          repeated binary field_id=-1 metadata (String);
        }
      }
    }
    repeated binary field_id=-1 assets (String);
    repeated binary field_id=-1 sharing_units (String);
    repeated binary field_id=-1 specific_data (String);
    repeated binary field_id=-1 validation_rules (String);
    optional group field_id=-1 metadata (List) {
      repeated group field_id=-1 list {
        optional group field_id=-1  {
          optional binary field_id=-1 id (String);
          optional int64 field_id=-1 role;
          optional binary field_id=-1 type (String);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why pyarrow can't read a file generated by another tool and I don't find details around this error.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What's the json corresponding to the corrupted parquet file like? How is the schema different for the files which work and the files that don't work?

Comment: Hi Kiva, did you ever find a solution for this? I am facing a similar problem, please see my question for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454902/unable-to-read-parquet-file-with-pandas-or-pyarrow-malformed-levels

Comment: No I didn't find a solution. We have totally rework our design to have more control on the schema. We don't use stream analytics anymore for this part @TomBomer

Comment: Ok thanks Kiva. I think the issue is fundamentally rooted in how my file has been written. Good luck your side!

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that there is a mismatch between the schema provided and how data is encoded in the file.  The error message could certainly use some more detail, but you could narrow down the correct column by trying to read each column individually until you can reproduce it.  You can then see if this is a bug in the code (based on schema) or a bug in the reader.

For more context parquet uses [repetition and definition levels](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet) to encode nested data.  When reading data the maximum such level is calculated from the schema.  Then before any decoding is done on read, Parquet will validate that all repetition/definition levels for the page fall within the expected range.   In this case a level of value "4" was found when only a max of three levels where expected.

Comment: Hi Micah, I have the same problem and have narrowed down to two columns but the `Malformed levels` error persists. Please see my question for more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454902/unable-to-read-parquet-file-with-pandas-or-pyarrow-malformed-levels