# Unable to read Parquet file with PyArrow: Malformed levels

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

**Assume** that I am unable to change how the Parquet file is written, i.e. it is immutable and so we must find a way of reading it given the following complexities...

```
In:
import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet("file_name.parquet", engine="pyarrow")

Out:
OSError: Malformed levels. min: 102 max: 162 out of range.  Max Level: 1
```

I have tried `fastparquet` instead of `pyarrow` as the engine but get a similar error: `ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size`.

And I get the same `OSError` when I do:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pq.read_table("file_name.parquet")
```

I have inspected the schema of my Parquet file:

```
In:
pq.read_schema("file_name.parquet")

Out:
list: list<element: struct<q: string, a: string>>
  child 0, element: struct<q: string, a: string>
      child 0, column_1: string
      child 1, column_2: string
column_3: int64
```

I have narrowed down the problem to `column_1` and `column_2` by doing:

```
In:
pd.read_parquet("file_name.parquet", engine="pyarrow", columns=["column_1", "column_2"])

Out:
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: No match for FieldRef.Name(column_1) in list: list<element: struct<column_1: string, column_2: string>>
```

This is to be expected since `column_1` and `column_2` are nested within `list`, so instead I do:

```
In:
pd.read_parquet("file_name.parquet", engine="pyarrow", columns=["list"])

Out:
OSError: Malformed levels. min: 102 max: 162 out of range.  Max Level: 1
```

I then tried `fastparquet` which is at least able to read `list`, but it fails to interpret the nested structure of `list`:

```
In:
pd.read_parquet("file_name.parquet", engine="fastparquet", columns=["list"])

Out:
     list
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
..    ...
455  None
456  None
457  None
458  None
459  None

[460 rows x 1 columns]
```

For further context, I used the `parquet-tools` CLI to inspect my file (below I have just shown the output for `column_1`, the output for `column_2` is the same):

```
In:
parquet-tools inspect file_name.parquet

Out:
############ Column(column_1) ############
name: column_1
path: list.list.element.column_1
max_definition_level: 4
max_repetition_level: 1
physical_type: BYTE_ARRAY
logical_type: String
converted_type (legacy): UTF8
compression: SNAPPY (space_saved: 85%)
```

`max_definition_level: 4` indicates that there are four levels of nesting for `column_1`.

**So essentially I need a way to unpack `column_1` and `column_2` when reading the file.**

My question is similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706305/parquet-pyarrow-malformed-levels#:~:text=This%20indicates%20that%20there%20is,until%20you%20can%20reproduce%20it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706305/parquet-pyarrow-malformed-levels#:%7E:text=This%20indicates%20that%20there%20is,until%20you%20can%20reproduce%20it).

Comment: How was the file created?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know! Which makes this a very difficult or impossible problem to solve. I have since contacted the creator of the file, but in the meantime I wonder if there is a solution.

Comment: Probably no solution beyond "it's corrupted". With time (I don't have) and fastparquet breakpoints, I could maybe figure out why. Note that fastparquet does support lists, but not lists of records.

Comment: Ok well thank you anyway. Hoping the file creator will address the problem.

Comment: I concur in this case the file is corrupt.  Based on the schema at least the repetition levels are written incorrectly (all values should be 0 or 1).   You can use [pyarrow's pq.read_metadata](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata.html) to get more information about the writer the file (which might or might not be helpful).